# MySQL - How to add alias syntax to subquery

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, in-subquery

I'm new to MySQL and still have issues with its syntax.  I have this query:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e
FROM table1
WHERE status = 'skipped' 
AND batchid IN (SELECT batchid 
                FROM (SELECT distinct batchid, date_format(uploaddate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
                      FROM table1 
                      WHERE uploaddate > '2011-01-26') AS t
               ) AS t;
```

which gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t' at line 1
```

The IN clause works:

```
SELECT batchid 
FROM (SELECT distinct batchid, date_format(uploaddate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
      FROM table1 
      WHERE uploaddate > '2011-01-26') AS t
```

I think my issue has something to do with the second table alias.  Can somebody show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an alias for subqueries appearing in the `WHERE` clause.

Leave off the final `AS t` (just before the semicolon) and all should be well.